# .NET Standard 1.2 - FileVersionInfo não existe

Tags: c#, packages, .net-standard

Segue código:

```
public static string GetVersion()
{
    return FileVersionInfo
                     .GetVersionInfo(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)
                     .ProductVersion;
}
```

Recebo erro:

> 1. CS0103 O nome "FileVersionInfo" não existe no contexto atual
> 2. CS0117 "Assembly" não contém uma definição para "GetExecutingAssembly"

Voltei .NetStandard com a versão mais antiga e recebo os erros acima.

Existe outra alternativa para obter a versão do pacote?

Comment: Qual a versão do .Net Framework? Porque o `FileVersionInfo` é do `System.Diagnostics` e o `Assembly` do `System.Reflection`

Comment: @LeandroAngelo estou fazendo com .net standard.

Comment: Com essa versão de Standart não é compátivel https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.fileversioninfo?view=netframework-4.7.2 talvez você seja melhor colocar 1.3 que deve ser compátivel com o que esteja fazendo ...

Comment: @VirgilioNovic Preciso 1.2 por causa .net framework 4.5.2. Não existe outra alternativa de obter a versão do package ?

Comment: Aqui só rolou com o `netstandard2.0` ou `netcoreapp2.0`... tenho só o 1.0, 1.1, 2.0 e 2.1 instalados

Comment: Matheus se está dizendo então que precisa que esse pacote rode também 4.5.2 ??? se for isso tem uma maneira de fazer isso e você colocar 4.5.2 e 1.3 no mesmo pacote!

Comment: @VirgilioNovic olha esse link: https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/standard/net-standard#net-implementation-support

Comment: Eu faria pacote com disponibilidade para o 4.5.2 e 1.3 por exemplo rodaria o pacote nos dois netframework...

Comment: @VirgilioNovic a versão 1.3 no mínimo é 4.6 do framework não é ?

Comment: Sim, mas, porque você colocou somente ele no pacote, tem uma forma de colocar duas ou mais configurações que ai o pacote de adpata, exemplo `<TargetFrameworks>net45;netstandard2.0</TargetFrameworks>` isso para você resolveria esse método seria compátivel

Comment: Você quer que o seu `netstandard` seja compatível com a versão 4.5?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic na verdade 4.5.1 ou posterior